# Wireless router has no internet access when connected to ADSL modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, adsl

I own a Broadcom BCM5354-based wireless router (Tomato 1.27 flashed) and an Aztech DSL605E modem. When both are powered up, the wireless router sometimes doesn't get internet access because the modem automatically logs itself in. I have to plug the modem cable to my laptop, manually disconnect the modem, and plug the modem cable back to the router to fix it.

Any suggestions about a permanent fix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have those specific router and modem, so I can't comment on the specific setting on them, but your modem should have a setting to either:

1. Attempt to login by itself (modem is doing the connecting, and then sharing internet access)
2. Allow Pass-through (allow Router / Computer that does the login, and the modem only simply passing through information) - Which I used for my own setting here at my house.

You can try to find some info on the modem setting / manual to see if you can set the modem NOT to login and get connection, but simply allow pass through, and then you can set your Router to establish (usually) PPPOE connection.

For the specifics of the setting, you might want to consider the manual of both router and modem, and also the HelpDesk for your ISP (or your ISP help page if any).

Answer (score 0):

The terms to look out for in the device configs are PPPOE (modem logs in on its own, router is usually either standard DHCP or static depending on your ISP settings - though DHCP is more common as the modem usually NATs with DHCP when it is doing PPPOE) or Bridged (pass-through mode where the router will then be set to PPPOE and will usually be set for DHCP).

If both are set to PPPOE you will have conflicts like the one described. There could also be issues with addressing depending on what is going on with your ISP and how you set up your router. More details about what has what addresses and what is set for static and DHCP might allow for more help in determining exactly what is going on, but it is likely some sort of conflicting settings.